# Is there another way to code #define SIZE 50 in c++

Tags: c++

I have a program and it needs to define 50. Is this the only way of doing it

`#define SIZE 50`

Answer (score 5):

With a const int?

```
const int size = 50;
```

This has a different meaning the #define though, and is much safer.  #define just does a pre-processing cut and paste, while defining a constant you maintain type checking.  You can't use this for everything that #define will do, but it will work for general constants and lengths of static arrays.

C++11 introduces constexpr

```
constexpr int size = 50;
```

constexpr expands the capabilities of constants to also include more compile-time computation.

Answer (score 5):

Using `#define`s for constants is decidedly "old skool" and has a number of disadvantages. Better to use `const`, e.g.

```
const size_t SIZE = 50;
```

Note that this applies equally to C++, C and Objective-C.

Comment: the type of the literal `50` is `int` though, so to retain that, `SIZE` should be `int` not `size_t`.  Although I'd agree that a thing called `SIZE` is probably not being used as an `int`

Comment: @Ryan: yes, I was reading between the lines and assuming that a constant named `SIZE` was most likely going to be used for memory allocation or similar purposes, but that could be a bad assumption.